# Flex ImageCapture/BitmapData limitations on small screens?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, image-manipulation, zend-amf

I have developed an application that in the end will save a captured image of a canvas that's scaled up to 4000 pixels then upload the result to the server using ZendAMF. This all works fine on all of my development machines. However, my client is running a small netbook and when he submits it to the server, the image on the server doesn't scale to Flash Player 10's awesome 4095 pixel limitation, it's down to the 2880 limit from flash player 9... I for the life of me can not figure out what's going wrong on his end and can not reproduce the error on anything I'm running. Has anyone run into anything like this before? I'm using the Flex 3.4 framework and requiring Flash Player 10. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the client has flash 10? Quadruple check before wasting any more time.

Comment: Yes, I had him go to Adobe's version checking page in both IE and Firefox so I can make sure he was on the right version. I was hoping that he wasn't on the right version because it would save me a ton of time. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this... it was completely of my own fault. I left a line of code that was acting out on a few systems. Thank you for trying.